# Recurrence, checkboard 2xn

Tags: recurrence-relations, mathematica

Good day,

I am finding out the recurrence relationship for a checkboard 2xn. 
I got 1-squares(1x1) and L shape, 3-squares to choose from to cover the table. n>=1

So a0= 1 since its just two 1-squares and a1= 5 (all 1-squares + 4 ways to rotate one L-square and fill the rest with 1-squares ).

Next, I take a2 and as always; 
**one** way to choose all 1-squares, 
**eight** ways to use one L-square and since this is just two versions of the previous checkboard (4 ways + 4 ways),
**two** ways to use two L-squares **a3 = 1 + 8 + 2 =11 ways.**

From this a4 = 2*11+5 = 27 ways and the recurrance relationship is  **an=2a(n-1)+a(n-2)**? I am on the right path here, right?

After I have found out the recurrence relationship I am supposed to use Rsolve to solve it and plot discrete plot.

```
iv1 = a[0]==1;
iv2 = a[1]=5;
rr= a[n] == 2a[n-1]+a[n-2];
sol = RSolve[{rr, iv1, iv2},a[n],n]
```

Here I am very lost. I read on Rsolve and I assume I can program it this way with rr as the recurrance relation(RR) and iv1 and iv2 as initial values. But, what does Rsolve do for me and how do I use the code for my discrete plot? I get the use of finding the RR, then I can find out the next element just by using the two former ones, but what about my RR am I trying to solve with Rsolve and what is it that my discrete plot will visualize about my RR?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please use plain english in your questions ; don't use unknown abbreviations like "I am finding out RR" (Respiratory Rate ?) that people who are not used to SMS style/slang  like me don't understand...